# Can I bind additonal keys to trigger Gnome's overview?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm not sure if overview is the right term but I mean the screen you see when you press <kbd>Super</kbd>. Gnome's full screen dash.

What I want to do is fairly simple. I just want to add an ***additional*** key binding to open the Overview. The Keyboard settings in Gnome seem to only allow me to replace key combinations or add new commands. If you know a command-line way to open the Overview, that might suffice.